# Table of contents Rmarkdown/papaja

Tags: r-markdown, tableofcontents, papaja

I have a question concerning Rmarkdown (papaja template) that I have not been able to solve so far (despite googling all day long...)

(Part of) yy YAML header is as follows:

```
---
title : "MY TITLE"
authornote: |
  "My author note"

abstract:  |
  "My abstract"
  
floatsintext      : yes
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no

csl:                "apa.csl"
documentclass     : "apa7"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
toc: true 

header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{lltable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\singlespacing}
```

As you can see I added a Table of contents by setting toc to true.
This works, however the TOC also includes the title, author note and abstract, which I do not want to be part of it (obviously).
How can I solve this?
(I know how to hide specific headers within the document, but can't figure it out for those things appearing before..)
I have already tried the Latex Syntax

```
\tableofcontents
```

but get the same results.

I would be more than happy if anyone could help me with this!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi Hanna, it is my impression that this might be a bug that will need some time to be addressed. What type of document do you want to create? (manuscript for submission, thesis, ...) I'm asking because the problem seems to be limited to manuscript-style output (i.e., `classoption: man`), but does not occur for document- or journal style output (i.e. `classoption: doc` or `classoption: jou`).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using the manuscript option as this work will be my Bachelor's thesis.

Comment: Then maybe using the document-style output `classoption: doc` might be a viable option. Still, I will open an issue on github about the problem with manuscript-style output, maybe we will be able to address it before you hand in your thesis.